# add data to webview html input in android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

i have a webview, am trying to load a webpage as shown in figure attached below, there is a dropdown and two inputs in need to get it loaded  by filling these values given by us in android webview

I have tried this code but its not working

```
 final String sectionName = getIntent().getStringExtra("sectionName");
        final String consumerNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("consumerNumber");
        final String billNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("billNumber");
        this.web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        this.web.loadUrl(Constants.Payment_URL);
        this.web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e("TAG", "sectionName:" + sectionName);
          view.loadUrl("javascript:$($(\"#sectionCode option\")[" + sectionName + "]).prop('selected','selected');$('#ConsumerNo').val('" + consumerNumber + "');$('#billNo').val('" + billNumber + "');");
              }

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }
        });
```

I need the web view get loaded with those values given in program[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKKa2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that with the help of javascript.

You can inject javascript into your webview in many ways.

I would advice you to use JavaSCript injector library. You can find it here.

https://github.com/henrychuangtw/WebView-Javascript-Inject